# Updating the tables using sql query in enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

We have the muliple EA.Elements which has the tag "UID".Now we want to update all the all the elements UID tag value at a time using query.So using SQL scratch pad we are trying to use the query "UPDATE t_objectproperties SET t_objectproperties.Value = "sssss122" WHERE t_objectproperties.PropertyID = 124". But the query is not executing for update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the scratch pad only for executing `SELECT` statements. Write a small script and place

```
Repository.Execute ("your scary SQL")
```

inside. This is a not documented, but well working operation

Comment: but we don't have the api Execute in EA

Comment: Read my last sentence

Comment: using script its working but using addin also will this work

Comment: I guess, that's a question. Yes, it will also work in an add-in.

Comment: can we use to insert into the table.For ex creating the new element of class stereotype instead using the API Elements.AddNew("","class")

Comment: Well, no. You might create "plain" things, but stereotypes are extremely complex since it eventually involves t_xref and a lot of voodoo to make it right. Even with creating simple things you should know exactly what you're doing when shipping round the API.

Comment: Deleteing the element through query is it possible

Comment: Since it will have primary key references can we use the sql query structure to delete the row by object_id

Comment: Yes, you can delete directly. Again: you need to know what you're doing. Many things are uncritical, but some can simply clobber your model. My Inside EA book is kind of a hacker standard for EA and it will save you quite some grief. But it will not save you from the bear traps. You need to experience them in your sandboxes before daring to approach them in live production systems.

Comment: In EA, section SQL Scratch Pad, not working query:  UPDATE t_objectproperties SET t_objectproperties.Value = "in" where Object_ID = 23573 And Property ="direction" . Also don't know how to update direction of a propertyFlow via query or via API ( Code: public void UpdateFlowPropertyProperties(Element flowProperty, Dictionary<string, string> elementProprieties) { foreach (TaggedValue tagValue in flowProperty.TaggedValues) { if (elementProprieties.ContainsKey(tagValue.Name)) { tagValue.Value = elementProprieties[tagValue.Name]; }} flowProperty.Update(); })

Comment: @Ice not a good idea to ask a question in the comments. Consider creating a new question and eventually linking to this one if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a nice and harmless one - if you lack drawing skills - to set the `size` and `position` of a **chartobject**:

```
EARepos.Execute ("update t_diagramobjects set recttop=-150,RectLeft=300,RectRight=400,RectBottom=-250 where object_id=40001")
```

Don't forget to ***Save*** before and ***Reload the current view*** after executing the update query.